# Xelatex polyglossia hyphenation

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, boxes, hyphenation, polyglossia

Is there a way to make the `polyglossia` package solve the hyphenation problem that presents itself in the log as "Overfull `\hbox`" automatically?

(Note: I find that having shorter lines—even for the entirety of the text—is much less worse than having protruding lines.)

I'm trying to get:

```
... end of line
end of line
... end of line
... end of line
```

...but what I have (and don't want) is:

```
... end of line
... overfullboxishere
... end of line
... end of line
```

Here's an example of an "overfull box" error:

[image: Example of "overfull box" error #1]

Another question: that could be related: `polyglossia` does not make hyphenation for other specified languages.

Example of "overfull box" error of other language with `polyglossia`:

[image: Example of "overfull box" error #2]

When I use the `\textenglish` command, the problem seems to solve itself:

[image: \textenglish command is used]

However, the resulting document is contaminated with `\textenglish`, and I don't want `\textenglish` in my document.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{itemize}
  \item Возможность работать с такими популярными как
  %  \textenglish{
    MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and Microsoft SQL Server.
  %}
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is too vague. Can you give an example?

Comment: It would be great if you provided a full compilable example.

Comment: If you want “automatic” hyphenation of English words you have two alternatives: either you use `\textenglish` (or an abbreviation), or you define a whole set of patterns for Russian and English together, rebuild the formats and teach Polyglossia to use these patterns for Russian. A simpler strategy might involve the `ucharclasses` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the best strategy is still marking the parts in English as such. However, if your English words are just a few, there are alternative approaches.

#### With `ucharclasses`

Define transitions to and from Latin characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{microtype} % better management of overfulls

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\hyphenrules{english}}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Возможность работать с такими популярными как
    MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and Microsoft SQL Server.

  \item Возможность работать с такими популярными как
  Возможность работать с такими популярными как
  Возможность работать с такими популярными как
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

#### With just Polyglossia

Define a set of hyphenation rules for the small number of words you need

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype} % better management of overfulls

\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\begin{hyphenrules}{russian}
\hyphenation{post-gresql or-a-cle mi-cro-soft}
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Возможность работать с такими популярными как
    MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, Oracle, and Microsoft SQL Server.

  \item Возможность работать с такими популярными как
  Возможность работать с такими популярными как
  Возможность работать с такими популярными как
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output is the same with the two methods. This still produces a small overfull box, but just 0.8pt, but there's not much to do about this apart from rewording.

Note that the `ucharclass` method is quite heavy, so using it for longer passages in English can slow down processing the file.